# preg_replace() Only Specific Part Of String

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace

I always have trouble with regex, I basically have a url, for example:

`http://somedomain.com/something_here/bla/bla/bla/bla.jpg`

What I need is a preg_replace() to replace the `something_here` with an empty string, and leave everything else in tact.

I have tried the following and it replaces the wrong parts:

```
$image[0] = preg_replace('/http:\/\/(.*)\/(.*)\/wp-content\/uploads\/(.*)/','$2' . '',$image[0]);
```

This ends up leaving only the part I want to replace, rather than actually replacing it!

Comment: Use `parse_url()` for this and do the replacement on the path portion.

Answer (score 8):

The following code is based on the description you provided:

```
$url = 'http://somedomain.com/something_here/bla/bla/bla/bla.jpg';
$output = preg_replace('#^(https?://[^/]+/)[^/]+/(.*)$#', '$1$2', $url);
echo $output; // http://somedomain.com/bla/bla/bla/bla.jpg
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` : match begin of line
- `(` : start matching group 1

  - `https?://` : match http or https protocol
  - `[^/]+` : match anything except `/` one or more times
  - `/` : match `/`
- `)` : end matching group 1
- `[^/]+` : match anything except `/` one or more times
  -`/` : match `/`
- `(` : start matching group 2

  - `.*` : match anything zero or more times (greedy)
- `)` : end matching group 2
- `$` : match end of line

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
$image[0] = preg_replace('!^(http://[^/]*)/[^/]*!', '$1', $image[0]);
```

Or you might consider just splitting the string to work on its individual components:

```
$parts = explode('/', $image[0]);
unset($parts[3]);
$image[0] = implode('/', $parts);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a simple string replace:

```
$image[0] = str_replace('/wp-content/uploads/', '/', $image[0]);
```

Or if you want to use a regular expression:

```
$image[0] = preg_replace('~(http://.*?)/wp-content/uploads/(.*)~', '$1/$2', $image[0]);
```

Comment: If instead of `/` you need to put value from a variable that you do not control, then you need to escape the `$` and `\number` characters, and this is quite a difficult task. Use `preg_replace_callback`, an example is in my answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Unreliable usage:

In `preg_replace('/(:\/\/.*?\/).*?\/()/', '$1$2', $string)`: if instead of empty string you need to put value from a variable that you do not control, then **you need to escape the `$` and `\number` characters**, and this is quite a difficult task.

---

Reliable usage:

For difficult regular expressions where you need to replace part of a string, it can be very useful to do so (and most importantly, **you don't need to escape `$newValue` for the characters `$` and `\number`**):

```
$newValue = '';

$newString = preg_replace_callback(
  '/(:\/\/.*?\/).*?\/()/',
  function($match) use ($newValue) { return $match[1].$newValue.$match[2]; },
  $string
);
```