# preg_replace all line breaks between specific BBCode tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, newline, bbcode

I'm programming a wiki with BBCode-like editing syntax.
I want the user to be allowed to enter line breaks that resolve to `<br>` tags.
Until here there's no problem occuring.

Now i also have the following lines, that should convert into a table:

```
[table]
    [row]
        [col]Column1[/col]
        [col]Column2[/col]
        [col]Column3[/col]
    [/row]
[/table]
```

All those line breaks, that were entered when formatting the editable BBCode above are creating `<br>` tags that are forced to be rendered in front of the html-table.

My goal is to remove all line breaks between `[table]` and `[/table]` in my parser function using php's preg_replace without breaking the possibility to enter normal text using newlines.

This is my parsing function so far:

```
function richtext($text)
{
    $text = htmlspecialchars($text);

    $expressions = array(
        # Poor attempts
        '/\[table\](\r\n*)|(\r*)|(\n*)\[\/table\]/' => '',
        '/\[table\]([^\n]*?\n+?)+?\[\/table\]/' => '',
        '/\[table\].*?(\r+).*?\[\/table\]/' => '',
        # Line breaks
        '/\r\n|\r|\n/' => '<br>'
    );

    foreach ($expressions as $pattern => $replacement)
    {
        $text = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $text);
    }

    return $text;
}
```

It would be great if you could also explain a bit what the regex is doing.

Comment: Umm, so what are you actually trying to do here? Just remove excess whitespace? `[\n\r\t]+|\s{2,}` => `''`

Comment: Oh, you mean be able to enter something like `[col]Colu \n mn1[/col]`?

Comment: No, actually I want to remove all `\r\n`, `\r` and `\n` inside `[table][/table]` tags, so this line `'/\r\n|\r|\n/' => '<br>'` won't echo `<br>` tags inside the parsed html `<table></table>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Style

First of all, you don't need the `foreach` loop, preg_replace accepts mixed variables, e.g. arrays, see Example #2: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

### Answer

Use this regex to remove all line breaks between two tags (here table and row):

```
(\[table\]([^\r\n]*))(\r\n)*([^\r\n]*\[row\])
```

The tricky part is to replace it (See also this: [preg_replace() Only Specific Part Of String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17852537/preg-replace-only-specific-part-of-string)):

```
$result = preg_replace('/(\[table\][^\r\n]*)(\r\n)*([^\r\n]*\[row\])/', '$1$4', $subject);
```

Instead of replacing with `''`, you replace it only the second group (`(\r\n)*`) with `'$1$4'`.

### Example

```
[table] // This will also work with multiple line breaks
    [row]
        [col]Column1[/col]
        [col]Column2[/col]
        [col]Column3[/col]
    [/row]
[/table]
```

With the regex, this will output:

```
[table]    [row]
        [col]Column1[/col]
        [col]Column2[/col]
        [col]Column3[/col]
    [/row]
[/table]
```

Comment: Updated my answer, now `[table] aaa [row]` will also match